# Azure Release Task App Center Distribute Taking Longer Than an Hour to Complete

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I Build and Release Pipeline in Azure devOps to build and release our mobile application to App Center. The Build definitions with build the solution and publish the .apk to an artifact.

The Release pipeline downloads the Artifact and push the .apk to App Center. However, the task that distributes it to App Center is taking over an hour to complete.

Our Agent is self hosted on a Windows VM. The CPU and RAM of this is VM does not go above 20%. So dont think it it a performance issue.

[image]

This is the settings I have for the task:

[image]

Comment: This is self-hosted, so could this just be a upload bandwidth or a network quality issue?